# Match array value with value in an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out how I can return a list with values from the `own` key in the array bellow if the object `name` value matches values in the lookupvalues array

```
lookupvalues = ["ross","linda"]
resources = [{own: "car", name: "bob"},{own: "bike", name: "ross"},{own: "plane", name: "linda"}]
wanted_output = ["bike","plane"]
```

I am struggling a bit with a good method to use for when I need to compare value in an object with array values. Is there a reasonable straight forward way to do this?

I must say how impressed I am that I got 4 replies with working examples at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (array method chaining) is that you could `filter` by `name` and `map` to grap each's `own`

```js
const lookupvalues = ["ross", "linda"]
const resources = [
  { own: "car", name: "bob" },
  { own: "bike", name: "ross" },
  { own: "plane", name: "linda" },
]

const res = resources
  .filter(({ name }) => lookupvalues.includes(name))
  .map(({ own }) => own)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
resources.filter(resource => lookupvalues.includes(resource.name))
  .map(resource => resource.own);
```

This will filter by the items that have names that are included in `lookupvalues`, and then transform the array into an array of the `own` values of those remaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the help of `Array#filter` and `Array#map`:

```js
const lookupvalues = ["ross","linda"]
const resources = [{own: "car", name: "bob"},{own: "bike", name: "ross"},{own: "plane", name: "linda"}]

const filterRes = (arr) => {
  const lookup = new Set(lookupvalues);
  return arr.filter(({name}) => lookup.has(name))
            .map(({own}) => own);
}
console.log(filterRes(resources));
```

Comment: Did you use a Set just for the optimization between `includes` and `has`?

Comment: @CoryHarper yes, here it won't make much difference but for a lengthy `lookupvalues` array it would.

Comment: Same reason I was thinking to perhaps suggest making lookup values just an object of `string => true` pairs, when it's initialized.

Answer (score 1):

```
resources.filter(item => lookupvalues.indexOf(item.name) > -1).map(item => item.own)
```